# error: [BC30057] Too many arguments to 'Public Function IsNothing(Expression As Object) As Boolean'

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm getting this error:

The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox233.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30057] Too many arguments to 'Public Function IsNothing(Expression As Object) As Boolean'.

When I add the "Group" to the code:

```
=Sum(IIF((IsNothing(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value, "Deposit_AcctNo1")),0,1))
```

This gives me a result and doesn't crap out on me, but doesn't give me the answer I expect:

```
=Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value),0,1))
```

I can't seem to add the grouping to it....

Answer (score 0):

I think your expression is wrong. It should be something like below,

```
=Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value),0,1),"Deposit_AcctNo1")
```

Please see if above expression works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  That's where my trouble is.  I can't seem to add in the Row Group.         The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox233’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Comment: what is Deposit_AcctNo1? is it dataset?

Comment: i think this not the answer that i am looking for